# How to maintain the maximum value in an array when the size is shortened

Tags: algorithm

Assume we have an array A[0:*n*-1] in size n and an int *maxElem* which maintains the maximum value of A[*i*:*n*-1], where *i* is initialized to 0 at the beginning and then added by 1 in each step.

So how to maintain this *maxElem* in a time complexity of *O(n)*? A simple method is to search the maximum in A[*i*:*n*-1] during each step, so as i goes from 0 to *n*-1, we have to do (*n*-1)+(*n*-2)+...+0 = *O(n^2)* times searching and it looks too time consuming. Does anyone know better algorithm comparing to this method?

Comment: Provide what language you are using and what you have tried. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions, not theoretical situations.

Comment: Got it. Will attach the code next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already calculated for `[i..n-1]` then you don't need to reconsider all the values in `[i .. n-1]` in `[i-1 i ... n-1]` again. So a better algorithm would be

```
+ get an array max_from[0..n-1]
+ set i=n-1;
+ max_from[n-1]= A[n-1];
+ for i=n-2 downto 0
    if(A[i]>max_from[i+1])
      max_from[i]=max_from[i+1];
    else
      max_from[i]=A[i];

Time_comlexity-O(n) Space-complexity-O(n)
```

`max_from[i]`==> maximum among elements `A[i],A[i+1],...,A[n-1]`